# In LEGO Harry Potter Years 1-4, why are all the gold cauldrons closed after finishing game?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

After finishing the story all the gold cauldrons (which contains Polyjuice Potion) are locked and without it some areas are unavailable. How do I fix that?

Comment: Surely you have enough characters (both good and evil) by that point to switch to them in freeplay? I've not played the game, but going on all the other Lego titles I've played, that's the way they work.

Comment: After finishing game? Sure

Comment: @ChrisF - with the LEGO Harry Potter games, a good chunk of the game takes place in Hogwarts, outside of an actual mission, and the only way to change characters in Hogwarts is through the Polyjuice Potion cauldrons.

Comment: @JasonBerkan - Ah. Good job I didn't answer then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [teh Internetz](http://www.gamespot.com/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4/forum/messages/platform/xbox360?topic_id=m-1-55421611&pid=960495), this bug is caused by the game failing to recognize that you unlocked the Polyjuice Potion during your initial playthrough.  From what I've been able to pull together, this occurs when you play the Polyjuice unlock classroom exercise in multiplayer.

I'm afraid there is no solution for the problem.  While you can go to the video room and watch the "Polyjuice Potion Intro" video to unlock the potion, you are then stuck in the Potions classroom, which just substitutes one game breaking bug for another.